# Generating Empty Array Structure in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to generate Empty array(not null) structure in bigquery and using following code :

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT
    STRUCT
      (
        CAST(NULL AS INT64) AS id,
        CAST(NULL AS BOOL) AS number,
        CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS name
      ) AS input
)

,CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(input ignore nulls) AS abc,
    ARRAY<INT64>[] AS xyz
    FROM CTE1
)

SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

In the output result the array generated has the value null for column abc, whereas for column xyz its an empty array. I want the output for column abc to be an empty array as well.

Comment: No! You cannot get this. Struct cannot be presented as just null! The way you get it now - is the way how to express it  -       {
        "id": null,
        "number": null,
        "name": null
      }

Comment: As mentioned by the previous comment a struct cannot be just blank or empty. A similar issue is created in this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/130890049) .

Comment: I was able to figure it out : 

SELECT
        ARRAY<
            STRUCT<
                    id ARRAY<STRING>,
                    number INT64,
                    time_field_1 TIMESTAMP,
                    name string
                >
        >[] AS abc
FROM `table.details`

Comment: I tried the query above and it I got these [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9lri.png). I just noticed that when queried it shows blanks instead of `NULL`, but when saving the results it just shows an empty `abc` array. Is this the output that you are looking for?